# How to comprehend the phrase "put them in affluent group of people"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've heard this phrase in Steve Jobs presentation about Apple's 'mothership' building plan in Cupertino.

The two ways I can come up to understand:

1. literally put them in the rich people
2. make them  affluent enough

which one is correct in this content?

Comment: You don't give enough context.

Comment: Yes, extracting a few words and asking for the meaning may be counter productive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://ericfadden.com/2011/06/kris-wang-and-the-apple-wifi-shakedown-of-2011/) is the quote by Jobs (scroll about 1/3 of the way down, or search the text for "affluent"), but you may have seen it [here](http://synthesis.net/2011/06/08/cupertino-to-apple-we-can-haz-free-internetz/), as well:

> An influx of uh, a tax base, an influx of very talented people, who are, you know, getting paid, would put them in a fairly affluent, uhh, group of people, uhh, and many of them would choose to make Cupertino their personal home as well as their professional home.

Jobs was speaking, so his sentences were far from perfectly executed; what he meant was that the residents of Cupertino would benefit from being in a neighborhood with the "affluent people" who work for Apple; also that those residents would have better chances at becoming affluent themselves by the possibility of their becoming employees.

Comment: you are the guy! I'm so amazed that you've found out the original article. Thanks

Comment: so the the 'them' is actually refer to residents of Cupertino, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's how I see it making sense.

Comment: I think the two "them"s are different - first is Cupertino residents, second is employees. His basic point is: we're bringing wealth into the community, which will have a beneficial effect on the community. 
Opponents of gentrification might disagree.